# The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value on AJAX call (Sitecore)

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, sitecore

I am having an issue with an AJAX call to a controller action, using POST and having 3 parameters sent and return JSON data. Whenever I try to call that on the developement server, it throws a **500 (Internal Server Error)**, with the description

`The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required.`

The main problem with this, is that on my local machine it actually works. The way the websites I am working on are structured, is without any App_Start files (so no custom route config).

Is there anyone who could help me with this? I am struggling with this for days now. Please keep in mind that I am trying this in Sitecore 7.1 (MVC) and IIS 7.5.

Thank you.

Best regards,
Marius.

Comment: Could you please include your routing code? and also your AJAX call code

Comment: I know is dumb what I'm asking, did you publish your .dll file to development instance  or build you developement instance solution.

Answer (score 0):

The absence of App_Start files in your solution doesn't guarantee there aren't any custom routes. Check Global.asax in your local environment vs your development server as this is another area where custom routes may have been set up.